# Why does this query have .?

Tags: php

I want to know why the following query have . and "" in ".$_POST['date']." etc.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO eventcal ('eventDate','eventTitle','eventContent','user',
'user_id') VALUES('".$_POST['date']."','".addslashes($_POST['eventTitle'])."',
'".addslashes($_POST['eventContent'])."')";
```

If I change to the following, will it make any differences?

```
VALUES('$_POST['date']','addslashes($_POST['eventTitle'])',
'addslashes($_POST['eventContent'])')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The query doesn't have dots, but is part of the string building process. Your question is PHP related, not (directly) MySQL related. And finally, your SQL allows SQL injection, so look for a better alternative like PDO.

Answer (score 2):

It is the PHP form of concatenation (The quotes mark the end of the strings). In JavaScript and many other languages it is the `+` character that concatenates.

```
echo "hello" . " " . "world!"; // Outputs 'hello world'
```

Yes, making that change would drastically change its meaning.

Finally, this is open to a *severe* SQL injection attack because `date` is not properly escaped.

Always sanitize your input and use parameterized queries where possible.

Comment: LOL... as if any SQL injection attack is not severe.

Comment: How can I sanitize the date? Can you give an example plz?

Comment: You could just use `addslashes($_POST['data'])` like the other variables, but you should probably check this post that has a few ways to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 1):

The "dot" operator is PHP's operator for string concatenation.  I think that using the `addslashes` function is a better idea than what you have in the first example but you will still need to use string concatenation as PHP's string interpolation only supports variables.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes inhibit variable interpolation, and as well the single quotes used in the array index would terminate the string.

Also, use a library that supports query parametrization instead of adding the values in like this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, only variables are parsed in double quotes which means your functions won't be executed in the second code block.